# firebase-ios-sdk adding some extra package dependency in my own Swift Package

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift-package-manager

I am using Firebase Messaging to make my own Swift Package for Push Notification Service. Now while I am adding the google package -  firebase-ios-sdk, then it is including all the other packages. But I don't want them in my Swift Package. So how I can remove all the other unnecessary dependencies or only can add FirebaseMessaging to it.

My Package.Swift file :-

```
// swift-tools-version: 5.7
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
name: "PushNotificationDemoPackage",
products: [
    // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
    .library(
        name: "PushNotificationDemoPackage",
        targets: ["PushNotificationDemoPackage"]),
],
dependencies: [
    .package(url: "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git", from: "8.0.0"),
    // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
    // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
],
targets: [
    // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
    // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
    .target(
        name: "PushNotificationDemoPackage",
        dependencies: [.product(name: "FirebaseMessaging", package: "firebase-ios-sdk")]),
    .testTarget(
        name: "PushNotificationDemoPackageTests",
        dependencies: ["PushNotificationDemoPackage"]),
]
)
```

[Package file screenshot is included here with red markup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBNpg.png)

[If first image link not working, then check here](https://ibb.co/8gvzF8X)

I am using Firebase Messaging to make my own Swift Package for Push Notification Service. Now while I am adding the google package -  firebase-ios-sdk, then it is including all the other packages. But I don't want them in my Swift Package. So how I can remove all the other unnecessary dependencies or only can add FirebaseMessaging to it.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am trying something similar. Also what did you use for the bundle identifier in firebase console. I would imagine you would not want to use the actual app's identifier as you are trying to keep firebase constrained to the library so you would not want a dependency on the main app correct?